# Datarelation with ultragrid

Tags: c#, datatable, infragistics, ultrawingrid, datarelation

I have a datatable like this :

```
Quantity   Price   Date     Comment
50         20      10/15    Buy 160
40         15      10/15    Buy 160
60         14      10/15    Buy 160
35         22      10/16    Buy 276
44         16      10/16    Buy 276
78         13      10/16    Buy 276
96         19      10/16    Buy 276
23         2       10/16    Buy 276
```

I want to see this in a ultragrid where the mother table are

```
Date Comment
10/15    Buy 160
and
10/16    Buy 276
```

and the child table are :

```
50         20      10/15    Buy 160
40         15      10/15    Buy 160
60         14      10/15    Buy 160
and
35         22      10/16    Buy 276
44         16      10/16    Buy 276
78         13      10/16    Buy 276
96         19      10/16    Buy 276
23         2       10/16    Buy 276
```

I know that I should use datarelation but I don't really know how
Thanks fro your help

Comment: Are you talking about having two different ultragrids? Or are you talking about expandable rows (called bands in ultragrid)? You can probably pull back the information from the DB and use LINQ to group the data and bind the grid to your results.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you would need to populate your single `Dataset` with `2 queries` in your datasource (which should be a stored procedure for example), to have it contain 2 `DataTables`, like e.g.:

```
Select Date, Comment From <yourTable>; -- DataTable1
Select Quantity, Price, Date, Comment From <yourTable>; -- DataTable2
```

Then, after the Dataset is filled from your `DataAdapter` in `C#` code, you would need to add DataRelations to the `2 DataTables` in your `Dataset`, as follows:

```
DataColumn[] parentColumns=null;
DataColumn[] childColumns=null;

parentColumns = new DataColumn[] { yourDataset.Tables[0].Columns["Date"], yourDataset.Tables[0].Columns["Comment"]};

childColumns = new DataColumn[] { yourDataset.Tables[1].Columns["Date"], yourDataset.Tables[1].Columns["Comment"]};

yourDataset.Relations.Add(new DataRelation("Date-Comment-Relation", parentColumns, childColumns));
```

Now, binding above Dataset (yourDataset) to your infragistics grid should give the UI as your desire (*similar if not exact*).

Give this a try, I hope this should work though I have not tried.

Comment: Also don't forget to check that your ViewStyle is MultiBand

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for the first part ofyour answer I wonder how I cam make this 2 datable easily, I can try by looping on it and say : 
if datatable["Date"] is different do a new datatble
But there any way to just cut the datatable by to datable with the same date ?

Comment: @francopshenri Add a using statement as `using System.Linq;` in your code file and see if any of the `LINQ` operations of the `DataTable` work for you to do this!! OR there must be some method of System.Data.Datatable itself that should help you e.g. the `Select()` method of `DataTable`.